# Как раскрасить терминал MacOS, чтобы бы он был таким же удобным как в Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, консоль

Всем привет. С недавних пор переехал на MacOS, у которого очень неудобный терминал (до этого недолго работал в Linux Mint). Например, при вызове команды "ls -l" терминал выдает список файлов и папок в одном цвете. Заголовок команды тоже никак не подсвечивается. Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я хочу, чтобы было примерно так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне раскрасить терминал Мака, чтобы он был похож на Linux? Хочу видеть другим цветом строки, в которых писал команды, быстро отличать папки от файлов и архивов и т.д.?

Comment: начните с определения того, может ли такое используемая вами версия программы *ls* (`$ man ls`).

Comment: @alexander, к сожалению я начинающий пользователь *nix систем и у меня почти нет опыта работы с мануалами в терминале. Но, кажется нашел: `Use ANSI color sequences to distinguish file types.  See LSCOLORS below.  In addition to the file types mentioned in the
                     -F option some extra attributes (setuid bit set, etc.) are also displayed.  The colorization is dependent on a terminal
                     type with the proper termcap(5) capabilities.  The default ``cons25'' console has the proper capabilities, but to display
                     the colors in ...` Это оно?

Answer (score 2):

В `~/.profile`

`alias ls='ls -G'`

```
Colorized_PS1 () {
    local RED GREEN RESET HOST_C WD_C USER_C ENDL

    RED='\[\033[31m\]'
    GREEN='\[\033[32m\]'
    RESET='\[\033[0m\]'

    HOST_C='\[\033[34m\]'
    USER_C="${GREEN}"
    WD_C='\[\033[33m\]'
    ENDL='$'
    [[ $(whoami) == "root" ]] && HOST_C="${RED}" && USER_C="${RED}" && ENDL='#'

    printf '%s' "[ \\A ] [ ${WD_C}\\w${RESET} ]\\n[ ${USER_C}\\u${RESET}@${HOST_C}\\H${RESET} ]${USER_C}${ENDL}${RESET}: "
}
PS1=$(Colorized_PS1)
```

[image: Будет так]

Comment: Спасибо. А есть какие-нибудь готовые решения, где не пришлось бы конфигурировать вручную?

Comment: Я не встречал, да и не искал, если честно. По сути в linux это все сконфигурировано тоже не автоматически. Просто дефолтная конфигурация